# Grammar of introductions

Tags: syntactic-analysis

If I were to say
"I am John Smith, New York University Alumnus"
or
"John Smith, RAF"
as an introduction, what would the latter half of the sentence be grammatically speaking?
I was thinking it could be a noun in apposition, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's an abbreviated form of of the obviously appositive 'John Smith, the officer of that name / an officer (etc) serving in the RAF', but I think some categorisations of appositives stretch this far (giving further information, descriptive; possibly defining, possibly not). Sling in a BA, MA, and (later) veteran of the Falklands, and you've got a list.

Comment: Perhaps we could call "New York University Alumnus" and "RAF" embellishments.